# Strdup each line into the array?

Tags: c

I have to allocate an array of 1000 pointers to character strings, read in each character string from stdin and strdup each line into the array. I did the following:

```
char *array[1000];
 int index = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      scanf("%s", &array[i]);
      strdup(array[i]);
 }
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way of going about it??

EDIT:

So, I need to plug the newline at the end of each line with a null character and I need to do it using the strlen function. I have the following:

```
  // Plug the newline where the end of 
  // a line is equal to '0/'
  index = strlen(array) - 1;    // line 30
  if (array[index] = '\n') {    // line 31
     array[index] = '\0';
  }
```

But Im getting the following error:

```
linesort.c: In function ‘main’:
linesort.c:30: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/string.h:399: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
linesort.c:31: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
linesort.c:31: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
```

Please advise!

Comment: I'm curious if you've tried this?

Comment: `scanf("%s" ...)` isn't a good way to read in lines of data (unless maybe if your lines never have whitespace). `fgets()` might be a better choice, or `getline()` if that non-standard (but common) library function is available to you.

Comment: @MichaelBurr How would I plug in the newline at the end of each line with a ’\0’, and not error out if there is no newline?? I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an intermediate array. You can't just store into uninitialized memory here `scanf("%s", &array[i]);`

```
char *array[1000];
char buf[50] ;
char buf2[50] ;

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    scanf("%49s", buf);
    snprintf( buf2 , sizeof( buf ) , "%s\n" , buf ) ;
    array[i] = strdup( buf2 );
}
return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: How would I plug in the newline at the end of each line with a ’\0’, and not error out if there is no newline??

Answer (score 1):

No

```
char *array[1000];

 for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      scanf("%s", &array[i]);  <-- array[i] has no memory here!!
      strdup(array[i]);    <-- array[i]=strdup(string) 
 }
```

self gave you a complete answer - hope you learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

This is very unlikely to work. You have a array of pointers, which is fine, but you're reading into undefined memory by using `scanf("%s", &array[i]);`, since it's not actually pointing at any valid storage yet.

Instead, you need to allocate a temporary buffer, e.g.

```
char tmp[500];
scanf("%s", tmp);
```

Then use `strdup` on the temporary buffer, e.g.

```
array[i] = strdup(tmp);
```

Comment: Someone on another post had said that scanf("%s, tmp) does not read a line of input, only a continuous sequence of non-white space